Create variable column pivot table for RDLC
I need to create a rdlc report that has variable columns.  Here is a sample of the data:
select '123abc' as SchoolId, 'Hoover' as SchoolName, 'JoeBob' as StudentId, 'Jumping' as Activity, 12 as amt 
into #data
union select '123abc' as SchoolId, 'Hoover' as SchoolName, 'TinaBob' as StudentId, 'Jumping' as Activity, 10 as amt 
union select '123abc' as SchoolId, 'Hoover' as SchoolName, 'JoeBob' as StudentId, 'Pushup' as Activity, 4 as amt 
union select '123abc' as SchoolId, 'Hoover' as SchoolName, 'FrankBob' as StudentId, 'Pushup' as Activity, 14 as amt 
union select '456def' as SchoolId, 'Underhill' as SchoolName, 'IamNotBob' as StudentId, 'Jumping' as Activity, 10 as amt 
union select '834abc' as SchoolId, 'Playdoh' as SchoolName, 'Homer' as StudentId, 'Drinking' as Activity, 35 as amt 
union select '1abc' as SchoolId, 'Slayer' as SchoolName, 'Franz' as StudentId, 'Eating' as Activity, 12 as amt 

Here is what the data would look like
123abc  Hoover  FrankBob    Pushup  14
123abc  Hoover  JoeBob  Jumping 12
123abc  Hoover  JoeBob  Pushup  4
123abc  Hoover  TinaBob Jumping 10
1abc    Slayer  Franz   Eating  12
456def  Underhill   IamNotBob   Jumping 10
834abc  Playdoh Homer   Drinking    35

and this is the result I would want, each school would be a new page from the pagebreak in the group in the RDLC
School          Activity    FrankBob    JoeBob  TinaBob
123abc-Hoover   Pushup      14          4       0
123abc-Hoover   Jumping     0           12      10

School          Activity    Franz
1abc-Slayer     Eating      12

School              Acitivity   IamNotBob
456def-Underhill    Jumping     10

School              Activity    Homer
834abc-Playdoh      Drinking    35

So the activities are variable and the names are variable.
I think getting the query to result in
School          Activity    FrankBob    JoeBob  TinaBob Franz   IamNotBob   Homer
123abc-Hoover   Pushup      14          4       0       0       0           0
123abc-Hoover   Jumping     0           12      10      0       0           0
1abc-Slayer     Eating      0           0       0       12      0           0
456def-Underhill    Jumping 0           0       0       0       10          0
834abc-Playdoh  Drinking    0           0       0       0       0           35

would work for the first part (but I'm having issues getting it to that point), but then I think I would need to find a way to get the proper names in the report since they won't be the same.
Or is there a better way to do this in the rdlc with linking multiple datasets together?
NOTE: This is just an example of what I'm trying to do, there are more of the "Activities" than "Students" so doing the pivot the other way isn't really feasible.
Thanks

What you're looking for is a Matrix Report in SSRS.
It'll automatically handle the dynamic pivoting of the data for you, using your source dataset that is currently row-like. You just have to specify the StudentId column as the  Column Group and set the page break on the SchoolId.

How do I set the column width of the person to 0 for the empty activities?  Right now it just has blank columns and huge gaps in them.

@Deleted_User You can probably use an expression leveraging the IsNothing() function to do so, but if that column is empty why return it in your dataset at all? I'd proactively filter out those empty rows from the dataset.

the problem is I need the headers to be based on the group and not overall.  If that person is not in the group it will have a blank for the column so this causes huge gaps.  So Column 1 may have the name changed to "Joe Bob" and in group 1 Joe Bob isn't in it, the only name in it is the one in Column 14 "Sam Iam".  When the report is rendered Columns 1-13 are blank so there's a huge gap to column 14.  In group 2 "Joe Bob" is in it but "Sam Iam" is not.  I need Columns 1-13 hidden for group 1 but need them visible on group 2 provided they have a name in it without the huge gaps.

@Deleted_User TBH it's kind of hard to follow what you're describing and drawing a picture of a simple matrix example and what you want to change about it might be helpful instead.
